# PhpStorm uppercase SQL keywords only

Tags: phpstorm

Is there a way in PhpStorm to convert all keywords to uppercase for a SQL statement and do not format anything else?
For instance I would like to format such a SQL:

```sql
select id
,order_number
    from orders
    where status 
in ('NEW', 'PENDING');
```

into following:

```sql
SELECT id
,order_number
    FROM orders
    WHERE status
IN ('NEW', 'PENDING');
```

I found that `Editor -> Code Style -> SQL` can be configured almost as I need. I can set `Word Case -> Keywords -> To upper`, but I can't disable any other formatting rules.

Comment: No, unfortunately there isn't

Comment: There are not many of them. You can just make a replace one by one OR you can make all the necessary statements like "(select|from|where|with|...)" and make replacement \U$1. It will work. At least in PhpStorm for sure.